# Azure Worker Role impersonating a domain account

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-worker-roles, azure-active-directory

My situation is I have an Azure Worker Role that needs to connect to an on-premises file share. The on-prem is connected to the Azure instance via VPN. Using Active Directory Federation Services to sync the on-prem AD with the Azure AD. The worker role is copying specific files from on-prem to Blob storage in the Azure account.

Is it possible for the worker role to impersonate a domain account? If so, how? Or how can I achieve my objective?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We do it, by using the class below

There you can easily call Impersonate and UndoImpersonation by passing in the token we have.  Please note that it's important to securely store the credentials in your cloud environment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;

namespace Codit.Common.Security
{
    public static class Impersonation
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr hToken);  //handle to token for logged-on user 

        [DllImport("advapi32.DLL")]
        public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        public static object Impersonate(string user, string password)
        {
            string domain = "";
            if (user.IndexOf(@"\") > 0)
            {
                domain = user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf(@"\"));
                user = user.Substring(user.IndexOf(@"\") + 1);
            }

            IntPtr securityToken;

            LogonUser(user, domain, password, 9, 0, out securityToken);
            if (securityToken != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var newIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(securityToken);
                WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = newIdentity.Impersonate();

                return impersonationContext;
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("The username or password combination was invalid, please verify your settings");
        }

        public static void UndoImpersonation(object impersonationContext)
        {
            var context = impersonationContext as WindowsImpersonationContext;
            if (context != null) context.Undo();
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing you could do, is creating a local listener (on your local server, running under the required account)  This listener could poll for files and push them to the blob store.